# Rails-4 Why can one not place a Forms class file in the views directory and have it load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am introducing discrete form objects into our project and separating that concern from the ActiveModel object.  The sources I have considered all suggest that these new class files should be placed into a directory under `app` named `forms`.  Which follows RoR convention.

I wondered if it was in fact more appropriate to put these things directly in the views directory above the associated template files.  But, when I moved the class file from app/forms to app/views it could not be found in the controller. And yet putting the class file in any other arbitrarily named directory under `app` worked fine.

I am under the impression that everything in `app` is automatically loaded by Rails and reloaded depending upon the current environment and configuration settings.  However, `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` reveals that `app/views` is not in the autoload path collection.  Clearly `app/views` is different.  But I cannot find any documentation that explicitly sets forth that this is the case nor why that should be so.

Can someone explain this behaviour and, if possible, provide a reference to the documentation covering this case?

Comment: From a structure standpoint I would advise against doing something like that anyway. The view directory is not supposed to have much (if any) logic in it other than templates for rendering data. Hence the controller/helper combination for defining the functions that would be used in the views. It would make much more sense for your `Form` class of objects to be in `app/forms` like you thought.

Comment: Well, I never really got to the point of making a structural decision one way or the other.  The question is why is the views directory handled differently from what one is led to believe is the case.  I just cannot find any explicit statement that says: "Everything in `app` except for the `views` directory is auto/eager loaded."

Comment: The views directory doesn't contain classes normally so there would be nothing to ever eager load, thereby making it a wasted search of it was an auto load path by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app/views seems to be on the autoload path per the source [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb), but it isn't eager loaded, which I believe means if you stick some class in there it wont be loaded until it gets required.